# Can't access Program Files (x86) on powershell

Tags: powershell

So, I'm trying to `clc` some files in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Whenever I try to `clc` them, I get  this message:

[image: error message]

Also, this happens whenever I do what's suggested in this [guide](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784&page=1):

> - Hold Shift and right-click on your remote folder.
> - Click on "Open command window here".
> - Enter powershell.
> - Enter clc C:\Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID\remote\* (clc + absolute path of your remote folder + * to affect all the files).

Is this a steam error or am  I doing something wrong?

EDIT: after enclosing the path with quotes, I get this error :

```
PS C:\Users\Jake> clc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\*"
clc : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\cfg' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ clc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...\440\remote\cfg:String) [Clear-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearContentCommand

clc : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\materials' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ clc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...emote\materials:String) [Clear-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearContentCommand
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a different method in the guide that worked. Since I can't accept my own answer, here this is.

> A simpler way but not as efficient:
>
> 1) Start Steam.
>
> 2) Disable Steam Cloud.
>
> 3) Delete all files in Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID.
>
> 4) Start the game to create fresh (and thus different) new files.
>
> 5) Exit the game and Steam.
>
> 6) Delete remotecache.vdf in Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID.
>
> 7) Start Steam.
>
> 8) Enable Steam Cloud and "Sync conflict" should appear in your game status.
>   Note that this method may not affect all the files (and you need to modify all of them if you want to delete all of them later).

Comment: You can accept your own answer. By the way the reason you probably got the access denied error previously was that Steam was running and had the file open.

Answer (score 5):

It is a PowerShell error, paths with spaces should be enclosed in quotes.

In the example, there are no spaces, so it works without quotes.

Try this:

```
clc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\96072243\440\remote\*"
```

Sidenote : please copy and paste text instead of an image, this is easier to read and copy

Comment: Ok, I will try raw text next time. EDIT: Ran into a problem with that. Since I don't want to paste the whole thing into this comment, check out this pastebin. http://pastebin.com/zrqfQi6H Happens with both methods.

Comment: _Access to the path is denied_ : this looks like a permission issue. You should launch an elevated PowerShell prompt as follows : Start > type powershell > hold the Ctrl and Shift keys while clicking the PowerShell shortcut. If you have another error, please edit your question to include it, no issue with posting a few lines of code here : )